# A listening thread in a serial library called by Flask app causes it to hang

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, serial-port, flask-socketio

I am building a local Flask web interface (not intended for more than one user) to control a Motor Driver from a Raspberry Pi. I found a library called Thorpy (https://github.com/UniNE-CHYN/thorpy) to control the Motor Driver and its working well with a test script.

Here is the Port class (cleaned from the irrelevant parts) to create the serial connection with the Motor Driver.

**Thorpy : port.py**

```py
class Port:
    #List to make "quasi-singletons"
    static_port_list = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    static_port_list_lock = threading.RLock()

    def __init__(self, port, sn):
        super().__init__()
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._lock.acquire()
        self._buffer = b''
        self._unhandled_messages = queue.Queue()
        print("Port : serial")
        self._serial = serial.Serial(port,
                                     baudrate=115200,
                                     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                                     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                     #write_timeout = 0.1,#rajout

                                     rtscts=True)

        self._port = port
        self._debug = True


        self._lock.release()
        self.daemon = False
        print("Constructed: {0!r}".format(self))

        self._thread_main = threading.current_thread()
        self._thread_worker_initialized = threading.Event()
        self._thread_worker = threading.Thread(target = Port.run, args = (weakref.proxy(self), ))
        self._thread_worker.daemon = True
        self._thread_worker.start()

        self._thread_worker_initialized.wait()
        print("Port : fin init")
        print("")
        time.sleep(5)


    @staticmethod
    def run(self):

        try:
            self._continue = True
            timeout = 1
            self._thread_worker_initialized.set()
            while self._thread_main.is_alive():
                print("run run")
                #Trick to avoid holding lock
                r, w, e = select.select([self._serial], [], [], timeout)
                msg = self._recv_message(False)
                if msg is not None:
                    # print("RUN :", msg)
                    message_handled = self._handle_message(msg)
                    if not message_handled:
                        print("Unhandled message", msg)
                        self._unhandled_messages.put(msg)

            self._serial.close()
        except ReferenceError:
            print("EXCEPT : STOP RUN")
            pass  #Object deleted
```

And now here the Flask server (relevant parts only) :
**webapp.py**

```py
from flask import *
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from thorpy.comm.port import Port

app = Flask(__name__)
regul = Regul()
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/pompe')
def page_pompe():
    return render_template('pompe.html')

@socketio.on('drv_connect')
def on_connect(state):

    serial_ports = [(x[0], x[1], dict(y.split('=', 1) for y in x[2].split(' ') if '=' in y)) for x in comports()]
    for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True, custom_match= lambda x: x.bDeviceClass != 9):
        try:
            port_candidates = [x[0] for x in serial_ports if x[2].get('SER', None) == dev.serial_number]   
            assert len(port_candidates) == 1
            p = Port.create(port, dev.serial_number)
        except :
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

When a button on the web page call the on_connect() function, the Port object is created and is stuck in the while loop of its "run" function (printing "run run" every couple of seconds), while the flask server hangs.

I suspect it has something to do with the part creating the thread inside the *init* of the Port class, but I have always used threading very basically and I don't fully understand it...

**What I tried**
I tried to create a thread (from the Thread library) inside the Flask app to call the creation of the Port object (and encapsulate its inner "run" thread) but it makes no difference.

If I create a Process instead of a thread, the Flask app stays alive, but I cannot have access to the port object from other functions (and cannot send orders the the Motor Driver).

Comment: I assume you are using eventlet or gevent? Any I/O that you perform must be non-blocking.  Did you monkey patch the standard library to make the I/O code non-blocking?

Comment: I use now gevent after trying eventlet. Just before you answered remarked that using debug=False solved the problem. I tried with keeping debug=True plus adding monkey.patch_all() and it also works well, so I think deactivating the debug mode must be equivalent to monkey patching ?

Comment: On the downside, this solution breaks a callback for a sensor on the Raspberry Pi (monkey patch deactivate that part of the code). I don't understand why because all of the others callbacks are working fine.